# Storage Optimization

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I am working on a project that uses Cloud Spanner, and my team wants to optimize the storage in our database.

We are interested in determining how much storage we are using by points like row or column.

**E.g.**

We have a column of type `STRING(36)` and a column of type `STRING(MAX)`
If both columns contain a 36 character string, will the storage used be equal?

I tried reading Cloud Spanner documentation and we are running tests that create new databases and compare the total size. We are expecting to learn more about how we can optimize our Cloud Spanner storage usage.

Answer (score 1):

Spanner will only use the amount of storage required for the values you actually write to such columns, for both `BYTES(MAX)` and `STRING(MAX)`. The only effect is a write-time enforcement of the size limit.